# Stacked Anchors

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I have three stacked images that I rotate through using Dojo fadeIn and fadeOut and a timer.  Only the href for the last one is ever available. Is it possible to rotate the href as well?

```
<div id="main-slideshow">
<a href="catalog_item.php?sku=1001"><img src="images/catalog/WRP21Aug10_0014.jpg" /></a>
<a href="catalog_item.php?sku=1002"><img src="images/catalog/WRP21Aug10_0015.jpg"/></a>
<a href="catalog_item.php?sku=1003"><img src="images/catalog/WRP21Aug10_0017.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS for it:

```
#main-slideshow
{
    width: 300;
    height: 400;
    position: relative;
}
#main-slideshow img
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I tried changing the z-index, but that doesn't appear to work. It's my first Javascript module using Dojo so I could have miss-coded something.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this framework/script, but it is likely rotating just the img tag. Can you specify which tag to rotate? I would say wrap each in a <div> and rotate the divs. Perhaps you need a different script?

Comment: You're right, I'm just fading in and out the <img> nodes.  I'll try the <a> nodes. And that fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would suggest fading in/out the entire  tag. Or even wrap them in three divs and fade them instead.

You could also rewrite the script to change the href attribute, but that would probably just complicate things. Hope that helps!